# How do I make RunAsync end?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am writing a Windows service to run something in a .Net 6.0 assembly, and Visual Studio 2022 has sent me down the road of hosted services and background tasks, both of which are new to me.

So here's what I have:

```
IHost thingInstance = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService(options =>
        {
            options.ServiceName = "My New Service";
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ThingWrapper>();
        })
        .Build();

await thingInstance.RunAsync();
```

ThingWrapper is the class that implements BackgroundService, and it contains this (somewhat stripped back, to avoid any confusion):

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        MyThing mt = new MyThing();
        if (mt.Start())
        {
            try
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Now wait until we are told to stop
                    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // This is normal for some situations
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                syslogger.LogError(ex, "Exception in service operation");
            }

            mt.Stop();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

}

This is fine if everything works.  When I debug it in Visual Studio then the hosted service runs until I press ctrl+C, and then the cleanup code kicks in.

But if the Start() method of my code fails, I want this whole thing to stop.  In Windows service terms, I want the service to stop running.  But the calling RunAsync only stops when ctrl+C is pressed.

How can I make RunAsync exit from within the executing task?

Comment: You need to de-nest your try/catch statements. Use the catches at the end of your first try/catch statement.

Comment: @JoshHeaps  No, because there's a difference between an exception thrown by the Start() method (I don't need to call Stop()) and a TaskCanceledException exception (where I _do_ need to call Stop()).

Besides, the question is how to make RunAsync end without an external trigger.

Comment: You should be able to use [`IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-hosting-ihostapplicationlifetime-stopapplication).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, that worked, thanks.  Took a whle to figure out how to get to it, but it does the job.